# How to authenticate one app using another app when both apps sharing same backend server

Tags: angular, cross-domain, ruby-on-rails-5, access-token

I have a Rails app, using it as backend and two angular 2 apps(Admin app and Main app). Both app share the same backend server.

When i logged in to Admin app it will show the list of users. Now what i want to achieve is when clicking on any user it should get logged into Main app with that user without asking for authentication

The issue that I'm getting is When I request from Admin app to Rails server, I'll get logged in from that user and gives response back to Admin app, I want to open Main app in another tab for that user without closing Admin app. I am stuck at how to send Admin app request response on Main app so that i can open app.

If I'll be able to set user details into localstorage of Main app, I think it will resolve the problem.

Please suggest me any other way if i am going in wrong direction

Comment: Saving the user's details (tokens) on the client via localStorage or cookies seems like a reasonable approach, but you already mentioned it, so what is the question

Comment: Issue is that I'm not able to store tokens on Main app's localStorage from Admin's app. I can store locaStorage to its own domain not for other domain.